# How to efficiently broadcast a large file from CMS to n clients in LAN

Tags: ssl, content-management-system, broadcast, file-transfer, large-files

I have a master and n slave devices in a LAN(WiFi) and a CMS on the internet.

I need to be able to push/download a multi-gigabyte video-file from a CMS on to all slaves by selecting it on the master. Traffic into the LAN must be encrypted, encryption within the LAN would be nice to have. If any slave drops a packet it should be able to request it either from the CMS or from other slaves. All devices in the LAN are tablets running android. The master shall be able to trigger the distribution of a video file located on a server in the internet to all slaves. This file transfer should be as quick as possible. The server will be set up anew so can run basically anything.

```
Internet ------------------------> WLAN
   |                                |
   |                                +----Master
  CMS                               +----Slave-1
  holds large file                  +----Slave-...
                                    +----Slave-n
```

The way I see it there are 4 ways to do this:

1. (Trivial)Give the slaves the filename and let them download the file individually. Amount of traffic: O(n*filesize)
2. (Trivial)Download the file to the master and the slaves download it from the master instead of from the internet. Traffic Internet: O(filesize), Traffic LAN: O(n*filesize)
3. Download the file to the master and broadcast it to all clients. Amount of traffic: O(2*filesize)
4. Use something to broadcast the file within the LAN. Since WiFi is a shared medium, theoretically each packet only has to be sent out once and traffic should be O(filesize).

While solution 1 would be simple to realize with e.g. scp downloads it clearly will be horribly slow and inefficient. I am looking to implement solution 4 if possible, but I don't know any available technologies that are able to do this out of the box. What are ways to achieve the broadcasting described in both 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

The specifics matter here.  Can you tolerate loss of some data?  How many clients?  What sort of platform compatibility must you have?

For this answer, let's assume you can't tolerate data loss.  Because of that, your multicast option isn't a possibility.  There's no telling whether or not a particular client would be able to keep up with the flow.  There's no guarantee the packets even get to the device.

Now, let's assume for platforms that you want to make this web-based.  Again, a strike against multicast.

There is an easy solution though... torrents.  Particularly if you use [WebTorrent](https://webtorrent.io/), it uses WebRTC's data channels which are encrypted.  You can take a further step and encrypt the content if you want, and share the key via other means.

A handful of clients will connect directly to your server, and other clients will download across the LAN.  You won't have to worry about any availability problems, as your server will still be available when needed.

Comment: No I want an intact multimedia file at each slave. Encryption shouldn't be the problem; via DH a shared secret between n parties can be established: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1027/63290 or simply share a symmetric key between all parties for a shared ssl connection.

Webtorrent is a good start but also not the solution. If that would be the solution, I could download it once to the master and then have the slaves download it from the master; but then I would have O(n*filesize) of traffic in the LAN which is n times slower than 2 or 3.

Comment: @jaaq It isn't going to be significantly more traffic on your LAN than it would be if you did multicast.  And as I said, you really *can't* do multicast in this case.

Comment: Sorry I meant broadcast. The idea is that since WiFi is a shared medium the router only has to send the packet once(if none are dropped). If it has to send the entire file to every device one by one, the delay would duplicate for every device. Or are there already some optimizations in regular file sharing technologies like TFTP, SCP or SMB I am not aware of?

Comment: You really should add more details to your question... specifics of what you're trying to accomplish.  There are a lot of tradeoffs that can be made.  You still haven't told us what platforms you're even targeting.  In any case, from a practical standpoint, you're not going to be able to send those packets over WiFi just once.  Particularly over WiFi, they *will* get dropped, and you have *near-zero* expectation of rate at which you should send that data.  Also keep in mind that the way torrents work is that each peer also serves that data, which may be very efficient in such a network.

Comment: added more details. End devices are all android tablets. Of course packets will get dropped via WiFi but it'll sure still be faster to send the file to a broadcast address and every slave recieves it and requests missing packets to be sent again; instead of downloading the file n times sequentially from within the LAN. In simple terms: If I am in a lecture hall, I can broadcast one sentence to all 300 students at the same time. The same should theoretically be possible with WiFi. Of course not all students will understand it all, but even if 5 ask again, it'd be quicker than sequentially.

Comment: In your lecture hall scenario, the lecturer knows that everyone is in the room, and generally knows how fast the students can absorb the information.  In a sentence in most any human language there is a form of forward error correction... context, verb tense, etc.  The lecturer also knows that students needn't write down everything word-for-word.  That's an entirely different problem.... (continued, next comment)

Comment: To use the same scenario, the lecturer would be dictating a large book to people in the hall.  Also, some people aren't really in the hall, they're outside the door.  Also, it's not really a lecture hall but a cocktail party, and the lecturer has no louder a voice than anyone else.  Also, it's critical for everyone to get the entire book down on paper, exactly as-is.

Comment: I get your point, but what you're asking for is surely going to cause more problems than it is going to fix.  Perhaps a direction for you to take would be to extend this torrent system with a method that gleans broadcasted data when possible, and stores it.  Then you get all the segmentation and checksumming magic off-the-shelf.